# Still No Efficient Way to UPDATE or DELETE in Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Can anyone guess why the developers of Entity Framework didn't include `UPDATE` and `DELETE` semantics?

I have a list of integer IDs. And I need to update all corresponding rows. Without going back to raw SQL or a stored procedure, the best I can do is load each and every matching row and update the object and then save it.

This takes way too long. Is there some cool way to handle this in the latest versions of Entity Framework that would be more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open source "[Entity Framework Extended Library](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended)" seeks to perform batch updates etc.

Here is an example from their github page:

```
//update all tasks with status of 1 to status of 2
context.Tasks.Update(
    t => t.StatusId == 1, 
    t2 => new Task {StatusId = 2});

//example of using an IQueryable as the filter for the update
var users = context.Users.Where(u => u.FirstName == "firstname");
context.Users.Update(users, u => new User {FirstName = "newfirstname"});
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. Bringing something like this into our project would be a big decision so I'm not sure we would go that road. Microsoft has poured huge resources into EF. I'd love to know why they think these features have no value.

Comment: I'm guessing they are keeping it core to it's goals, rather than bulk updates etc where other tooling is more specialised. It provides good break out points, thus we use EF where it's appropriate and then drop into stored procedures when performance is a problem. I can't talk for the team but there are some discussions on codeplex site.

Comment: But I must admit, I do myself use EF for bulk stuff as it's very convenient to do so :-)

Comment: It *is* convenient. But having to load rows in order to update or delete them is just brain dead.

Comment: Yeah when I say *convenient* I take the performance hit in exchange for the EF magic, so I'd like to see 'bulk features' added even though I probably should be using SSIS etc. You can turn of change tracking and trigger it when you've done your changes to get a massive performance improvement... my comments are getting a bit chatty.. so let's move this to chat if we want to chat more. :-)